# Is there any relation between Movie Clip Editor and Video Sequence Editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a video, consisting of several shots with cuts between them. I would like to make some 3D reconstruction within it. Particulatly, I would like to place some excess 3D modelled objects into the scene.

In `Movie Clip Editor` I can load some clip from external file and make some reconstruction against it. But this reconstruction should not extend the shots margins. How to denote shot margins here?

In `Video Sequence Editor` I can cut strips, but these cuts are seem to be unrelated with what happening in `Movie Clip Editor`.

Is there any relation between them, or they are completely separate? Can I load some strip into `Movie Clip Editor`, or perform clip editing on strips from `Video Sequence Editor`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Movie Clip Editor you can define the duration of the clip by setting start and frame offset and using the Footage settings tab.

[image]

The events on the Video sequence editor are not connected with the Movie Clip Editor in any way. The VSE has its own viewer, unrelated to the MCE . You can only load Strips and edit on the VSE. The 3D scene can be loaded into the VSE as a strip, but the events on the VSE are not available in the 3D environment. There is an addon to send VSE strips to the compositor and back ([link to blenderartist's thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?221567-Edit-strip-with-compositor)), but it's not a fully implemented solution yet.

Comment: The question was asked 3 years ago, but I am curious about updates: is the situation still the same in 2017 and blender 2.78?